# Extracting a particular value

Tags: redis

I am just learning redis and I have a question regarding extracting the value of a sorted set. Basically, is there a method for sortedset that extracts the value given a particular key? Below is some sample code:

```
     if (status == null)
                {
                    redis1.SortedSetAdd("Number:" + id, User, 1);
                    return Ok("Success");

                }
     else
                {
                    /*get value from that key and increment by 1;*/
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZSCORE: http://redis.io/commands/zscore. However if you want to increment you should use ZINCRBY.